# Do not submit empty textbox c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a validation on a textbox that it will not be submitted when its empty. It works that it will not submit when there is a whitespace but it still get submitted when I havent typed anything yet on the textbox.

Below is the code on c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{0,8}$");
    if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    {
        button1.Text = "Submitted";
        button1.Enabled = false;
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        int ver = 2013;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to visual c# " + ver.ToString(), "Greeting");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or WinForms? What is "submission" in this context?

Comment: try to switch ur IF statement. put the checking emptybox on the first if, and put the checking Match in the else if

Comment: `Click` event registered with button,so event will be triggered irrespective of , textbox content.

Comment: @Mark thanks it worked

Comment: @Dren your regex accepts nothing, hence submitting when empty. Try changing `{0,8}` to `{1,8}`

Comment: @Andre@Grant You guys are right my regex should indicate to accept at least 1 character hence there is no need of the else if block and decrease the lines of code. Great approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-form your condition like this

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{0,8}$");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
}
else if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
{
    button1.Text = "Submitted";
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    int ver = 2013;
    MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to visual c# " + ver.ToString(), "Greeting");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `RegEx` statement allows empty values. Change the `0` to a `1` in `{0,8}` and remove the `else if` block that catches empty values (`null` values on a `TextBox` aren't even possible).

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{1,8}$");
if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
{
    button1.Text = "Submitted";
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string name = textBox1.Text;
    int ver = 2013;
    MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to visual c# " + ver.ToString(), "Greeting");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking for the empty text first, then check the regex, since the regex allows for 0 to 8 characters.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || textBox1.Text == "") {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
    } else {
        Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{0,8}$");
        if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        {
            button1.Text = "Submitted";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            int ver = 2013;
            MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to visual c# " + ver.ToString(), "Greeting");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
        }
    }
}
```

If it is supposed to be exactly 8, you need to change the `{0,8}` part of your regex to `{8}`, and you can leave the rest of your code exactly how it is.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trim() to discard white space

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{0,8}$");
    if (pattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    {
        button1.Text = "Submitted";
        button1.Enabled = false;
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        int ver = 2013;
        MessageBox.Show("Hello " + name + "! Welcome to visual c# " + ver.ToString(), "Greeting");
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()) || textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please type a valid 8 character string on the textbox!");
    }
```

}